# FFMPEG - latest build doesn't work, earlier build does

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have been using FFMPEG to overlay coloured rectangles on a video.  I updated FFMPEG and it no longer works.  No error is issued, it just doesn't do the job - the resulting video is the same as the input video.  Here's the script:

```
FFMpeg -y -i Input.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "nullsrc=size=1920x1080,  \
  drawbox=x=200:y=100:w=300:h=150:t=20:c=yellow,  fade=in:st=10:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=20:d=2:alpha=1 [tmp1]; \ 
  nullsrc=size=1920x1080,  \
  drawbox=x=240:y=140:w=300:h=150:t=20:c=red,  fade=in:st=15:d=1:alpha=1, fade=out:st=25:d=2:alpha=1 [tmp2]; \
  [tmp1][tmp2] overlay=0:0:shortest=1[tmp3]; \
  [0:v][tmp3] overlay=0:0:shortest=1" \
  Output.mp4
```

The output video should be the input video with a yellow rectangle added from T=10 to T=20 and a red rectangle from T=15 to T=25, fading them in and out.

The version that was working (3.4) was one that came with an ImageMagick installation.  The version I updated it to was 4.2.3.  I tried it on various other builds I had lying around and it only works with 3.4.

It seems unlikely that this is a regression so I haven't submitted a bug report.  I  figure it's more likely that I'm not doing something correctly and 3.4 is more lenient on its interpretation of my command.

Whatever, I prefer to be working with a current build, so I invite comments on what the reasons might be.

Console dump of 3.4 run

```
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:01:48.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1693 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1562 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Output-34.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
frame= 3260 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=   21461kB time=00:01:48.56 bitrate=1619.3kbits/s speed=0.828x
video:19713kB audio:1634kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.534457%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] frame I:14    Avg QP:17.68  size:208205
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] frame P:844   Avg QP:21.55  size: 16867
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] frame B:2402  Avg QP:28.40  size:  1263
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  2.9%  0.4% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] mb I  I16..4: 14.0% 39.6% 46.4%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.7%  0.2%  P16..4: 20.2%  9.1%  4.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:64.8%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 12.4%  0.4%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:87.1%  L0:42.9% L1:55.2% BI: 1.9%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] 8x8 transform intra:45.2% inter:68.3%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 64.4% 81.6% 45.1% inter: 2.9% 4.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 26%  6% 37%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 20% 15%  5%  6%  7%  7%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 28%  8%  4%  6%  6%  6%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 25% 28% 10%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] ref P L0: 70.4% 15.3% 10.8%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] ref B L0: 93.1%  6.0%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] ref B L1: 97.8%  2.2%
[libx264 @ 000001f0d4a0e6a0] kb/s:1486.03
[aac @ 000001f0d4a10a20] Qavg: 1586.609
```

And 4.2.3

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:01:48.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1693 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1562 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Output-423.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame= 3260 fps= 28 q=-1.0 Lsize=   21425kB time=00:01:48.56 bitrate=1616.7kbits/s speed=0.917x
video:19686kB audio:1625kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.535352%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] frame I:14    Avg QP:17.68  size:208355
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] frame P:844   Avg QP:21.54  size: 16838
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] frame B:2402  Avg QP:28.43  size:  1261
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  2.9%  0.4% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] mb I  I16..4: 13.9% 39.7% 46.4%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.7%  0.2%  P16..4: 20.2%  9.1%  4.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:64.8%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 12.4%  0.4%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:87.1%  L0:42.9% L1:55.2% BI: 1.9%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] 8x8 transform intra:45.3% inter:68.3%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 65.2% 82.4% 45.8% inter: 2.9% 4.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 24%  6% 38%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 19% 14%  5%  6%  7%  7%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 28%  8%  4%  6%  6%  6%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 24% 28% 11%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] ref P L0: 70.4% 15.3% 10.8%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] ref B L0: 93.1%  6.0%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] ref B L1: 97.8%  2.2%
[libx264 @ 000001e7b4531d40] kb/s:1483.98
[aac @ 000001e7b47fa800] Qavg: 1462.566
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the drawbox filter whereby the source alpha pixels would be replaced with the drawbox color's alpha (usually opaque) instead of preserving or blending it. Your command relies on that remaining the case, but I changed that after 3.4 series, so you now have to tell drawbox to replace the alpha for the box pixels.

So,

```
drawbox=x=200:y=100:w=300:h=150:t=20:c=yellow:replace=1
```

and

```
drawbox=x=240:y=140:w=300:h=150:t=20:c=red:replace=1
```

Comment: OK, too late to try it tonight but, will the alpha blending still work (I. E. The fade)? I don't get what "replace =1"does. It sounds like what I don't want!

Comment: All good.  Worked fine on all builds I had that supported the `replace=` option.  Many thanks.